# display Blob image in java with primefaces

Tags: java, mysql, primefaces, xhtml, blob

I need to diplay blob type image data in java web page which is use primefaces. but it won't diplay image but display icon of a image. Glassfish server out put get nullpoint exception with some errors

Server output =

```
WARNING: Setting non-serializable attribute value into ViewMap: (key: phonesBean, value class: bean.PhonesBean)
SEVERE: Error in streaming dynamic resource. null
SEVERE: Error in streaming dynamic resource. null
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.primefaces.application.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:67)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:591)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

SEVERE:     at org.primefaces.application.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:67)
SEVERE:     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:591)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
SEVERE:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.primefaces.application.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:67)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:591)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

SEVERE:     at org.primefaces.application.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:67)
SEVERE:     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:591)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)  
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
SEVERE:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

HTML =

```
<p:dataGrid var="phone" value="#{phonesBean.phoneList}" columns="8"
                             rows="12" paginator="true"  
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
    rowsPerPageTemplate="9,12,15" style="text-align: center;">  

                                   <p:panel header="#{phone.model}" style="text-align:center;width: 100px">  
                                    <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%">  
                                        <p:graphicImage value="#{phone.image}"/>


                                    </h:panelGrid>
```

java code =

```
 private void blobToStreamedContentConvertor(){
    try{
    Blob imageBlob1 = new SerialBlob(imageBlob);
    InputStream stream = imageBlob1.getBinaryStream();
    image = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "image/jpg");
    createImageValue();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("e = "+e);
    }
}

private void createImageValue(){  

//        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
//        imageValue = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id");
    imageValue = String.valueOf(image);
}
```

Note - After quering the DB for images image take toa blob type variable...

Comment: Did you try to debug the code to see what the values are at runtime?

Comment: Yes some hex values are display

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in primefaces, see [this](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3821) and [this](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3446).

You could try to change the scope of your bean from `@ViewScoped` to `@SessionScoped`. If that doesn't help, or is not an option then I suggest you post this on the [primefaces forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/) or [google code](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/).

Answer (score 0):

The EL used in your JSF page is used to retrieve the image when the browser asks for it. 
But the El contains the row var of the table. In your case shortcutDetails.imageContent isn't 
known outside the table.
If you try to retrieve an object singularly and display the image it will work perfectly but inside a loop it will not.

Below you can find a solution for this kind of problem:

http://jsfcorner.blogspot.be/2012/11/advanced-primefaces-graphic-image.html

Hope it works well for you!